# How to create drop down filter results in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've got an Angular app with a search bar at the top of a webpage. This search bar is a filter that displays subsets of a JSON data array. I'd like for this filter to display its results in a fashion that doesn't affect the DOM on the rest of the page (that way, if the filter returns a ton of results, a drop down box with its own scrolling option will appear, as opposed to the results pushing down the underlying HTML page).

The solution I came up with was to wrap my `ng-repeat` and filter in a div and give that div an `absolute` position in my CSS. Is there a better way to do this? This seems awfully hackish and not very Angular to me, but I can't find any other drop down filter solutions.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a typeahead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a working implementation in `AngularStrap` :

- Demo : http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeahead#typeaheads
- Source :
  https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js