# Angular JS: Autocomplete for key in obj array

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

```
$scope.users = [{username:user1},{username:user2},{username:user3}];
```

I have objects array, and i need to make input of search with autocomplete. I need to filter users by input symbols in input field.

Comment: try Typeahead from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: there is no examples of autocomplete

Comment: type 'a' in first input http://plnkr.co/edit/g1ULxzKQn7C1fjIF0M8P?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[How to create drop down filter results in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287380/how-to-create-drop-down-filter-results-in-angularjs)

this can help

http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeahead#typeaheads